# What software prerequisite are required for a C# application at client side?

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment, crystal-reports

I have developed a C# application with the .NET framework v4.0 and back end with SQL Server 2012, it includes Crystal Reports v13. When deploying to client side, I have installed .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2012, but still there is an error for Crystal Reports. How to get rid of it, and is there any other way besides installing SQL Server 2012 for database to work properly?

Comment: If you took a dependency on Crystal reports, you will have to deploy/install it. You don't have to install the server as I expect it should be insalled on a server

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install crystal reports v 13 as well. If the database is in a server, you don't have to install SQL server in client side. Just create a sql connection to the server.

Comment: and is there any way to avoid installing bulky sql server 2012?

Comment: SQL Server should be installed on the server. Then create a sql connection to the server on the client pc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Crystal Reports Redistributable` version at client side.

And as far as database is concerned, you can use `Compact Edition` of  SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you, but compact edition requires entire database to be shifted to compact edition via script or any other way, since it supports .sdf format, whilst currently my database is in .mdf format.

Comment: Also you can attach a .mdf file in application folder and create setup along with that .mdf file. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to installed CRVS for this . Just check below link and installed appropriate.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3424543

Comment: A crystal report Runtime Version was required. Thankyou.
For anyone else facing any of the above issue, for deploying a Dotnet desktop application, you need to check following things at the deployment pc:
Dotnet version compatible to your application
A Database runtime/Management system of whatever database used
Reporting runtime tool (if crystal report is used)
Finally a valid connection string.